# How to run these XSL templates in sequence

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

To preface this, I've only recently gotten into the more advances things we can do with XSL.

I'm currently trying to transform the data provided in the XML file and then convert the output of that into a JSON file.

I can do each of these things individually (using XSL I found online for the JSON) and I've tried to run this using apply-templates, call-template, mode="run2" etc. and cannot get them to behave. I can only ever get one or the other.

The XSL I'm using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<!-- Extract required information-->
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xmlOutput">
    <jobDetails>
      <orderId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Order/OrderId"/>
      </orderId>
      <xsl:variable name="jobId" select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/OrderLineId" />
      <orderLine>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($jobId,'d')"/>
      </orderLine>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine">
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/>
        </name>
        <copies>
          <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
        </copies>
        <url>
          <xsl:value-of select="AssetUrl"/>
        </url>
        <nestQueueName>smile_test</nestQueueName>
        <customer_info>
          <first_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/Customer/FirstName"/>
          </first_name>
          <last_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/Customer/LastName"/>
          </last_name>
          <street1>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Address1"/>
          </street1>
          <street2>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Address2"/>
          </street2>
          <city>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Town"/>
          </city>
          <state>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/State"/>
          </state>
          <country>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Country"/>
          </country>
          <phone>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Phone"/>
          </phone>
          <email>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Email"/>
          </email>

        </customer_info>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </jobDetails>
  </xsl:template>

<!--Convert XML to JSON-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="xmlOutputVar">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$xmlOutputVar"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Object or Element Property-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
        "    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
" :    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Array Element -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Object Properties -->
  <xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
"</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "        <xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>
" :[        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>
] }</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Attribute Property -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">"    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
" : "    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
",
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The two aren't configured to run together at the moment since I've stripped it back to be simplified, but the pipeline should be Source XML -> Extract information template -> Convert to JSON templates.

I know these two template/template sets work as I've tried them individually on the source XML (see below), but when I try and link them up I cannot get the right output.

Can anyone help?

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OrderId>1234</OrderId>
    <StoreFrontId>00</StoreFrontId>
    <StoreFrontName>Example Store</StoreFrontName>
    <Amount>0.0000</Amount>
    <Taxes>0.0000</Taxes>
    <TotalDiscount>0.0000</TotalDiscount>
    <OrderStatusId>1</OrderStatusId>
    <OrderStatus>Confirmed</OrderStatus>
    <PaymentStatusId>2</PaymentStatusId>
    <PaymentStatus>Paid</PaymentStatus>
    <ShippingStatusId>1</ShippingStatusId>
    <ShippingStatus>Pending</ShippingStatus>
    <OrderDiscount>0.0000</OrderDiscount>
    <SubTotalDiscountInclTax>0.0000</SubTotalDiscountInclTax>
    <SubTotalDiscountExclTax>0.0000</SubTotalDiscountExclTax>
    <ShippingTax>0.0000</ShippingTax>
    <ShippingPrice>0.0000</ShippingPrice>
    <ShippingMethod>Test</ShippingMethod>
    <ShippingMethodSystemName>Test</ShippingMethodSystemName>
    <ShippingMethodCode>24</ShippingMethodCode>
    <PaymentMethod>Payments.PurchaseOrder</PaymentMethod>
    <VatNumber />
    <OrderWeight>1.0000</OrderWeight>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber />
    <Customer>
        <CatfishId>50242</CatfishId>
        <ExternalId>External ID</ExternalId>
        <Email>test@email.com</Email>
        <FirstName>TestFirst</FirstName>
        <LastName>TestLast</LastName>
        <PhoneNumber>01234567890</PhoneNumber>
        <CompanyName>CompanyName</CompanyName>
        <AddressLine1>AddressLine1</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>AddressLine2</AddressLine2>
        <Town>Town</Town>
        <County>County</County>
        <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <ZipPostalCode>AB01 1AB</ZipPostalCode>
    </Customer>
    <OrderNotes />
    <OrderDateUtc>2018-07-27</OrderDateUtc>
    <DispatchBy>2018-07-27</DispatchBy>
    <BillingAddress>
        <ExternalId />
        <FirstName>Billing</FirstName>
        <LastName>Address</LastName>
        <Address1>BALO</Address1>
        <Postcode>BA73 5ST</Postcode>
        <State>Aberdeenshire</State>
        <Town>BAT</Town>
        <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <Email>test@email.com</Email>
        <CompanyName>BillingAddressCompany</CompanyName>
    </BillingAddress>
    <ShippingAddress>
        <ExternalId />
        <FirstName>Billing</FirstName>
        <LastName>Address</LastName>
        <Address1>BALO</Address1>
        <Postcode>BA73 5ST</Postcode>
        <State>Aberdeenshire</State>
        <Town>BAT</Town>
        <Country>United Kingdom</Country>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <Email>test@email.com</Email>
        <CompanyName>BillingAddressCompany</CompanyName>
    </ShippingAddress>
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine>
            <OrderLineId>v2604</OrderLineId>
            <ProductExternalId>External ID</ProductExternalId>
            <ProductVariantExternalId>Variant External ID</ProductVariantExternalId>
            <Sku>0000</Sku>
            <ProductName>ProductName</ProductName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>0.0000</TotalPrice>
            <TotalTax>0.0000</TotalTax>
            <Weight>1.0000</Weight>
            <DiscountAmountInclTax>0.0000</DiscountAmountInclTax>
            <DiscountAmountExclTax>0.0000</DiscountAmountExclTax>
            <AssetUrl>urlGoesHere</AssetUrl>
            <PrintParameters />
            <ProductAttributes>
                <ProductAttribute>
                    <Name>Attribute1</Name>
                    <Value>A</Value>
                    <Values>
                        <ProductAttributeValue>
                            <Value>A</Value>
                        </ProductAttributeValue>
                    </Values>
                </ProductAttribute>
                <ProductAttribute>
                    <Name>Attribute2</Name>
                    <Value />
                    <Values>
                        <ProductAttributeValue>
                            <Value />
                        </ProductAttributeValue>
                    </Values>
                </ProductAttribute>
                <ProductAttribute>
                    <Name>Attribute3</Name>
                    <Value />
                    <Values>
                        <ProductAttributeValue>
                            <Value />
                        </ProductAttributeValue>
                    </Values>
                </ProductAttribute>
                <ProductAttribute>
                    <Name>Attribute4</Name>
                    <Value />
                    <Values>
                        <ProductAttributeValue>
                            <Value />
                        </ProductAttributeValue>
                    </Values>
                </ProductAttribute>
            </ProductAttributes>
            <Totals>
                <UnitPrice>0.00000000</UnitPrice>
                <TotalPrice>0.00000000</TotalPrice>
                <TotalTax>0.00000000</TotalTax>
                <DiscountAmountInclTax>0.00000000</DiscountAmountInclTax>
                <DiscountAmountExclTax>0.00000000</DiscountAmountExclTax>
            </Totals>
        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
    <CheckoutAttributes />
    <Totals>
        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
        <TotalPrice>0.00000000</TotalPrice>
        <TotalDiscount>0</TotalDiscount>
        <OrderDiscount>0.00000000</OrderDiscount>
        <SubTotalDiscountInclTax>0.00000000</SubTotalDiscountInclTax>
        <SubTotalDiscountExclTax>0.00000000</SubTotalDiscountExclTax>
        <TotalTax>0.00000000</TotalTax>
        <ShippingPrice>0.00000000</ShippingPrice>
        <ShippingTax>0.00000000</ShippingTax>
    </Totals>
</Order>
```

P.S. It's not possible for me to run two separate XSL files on the XML, nor is it possible to use anything beyond XSL 1.0

EDIT:
I've amended the XSLT to be the following after listening to the advice given in a comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
   version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<!-- Extract required information-->
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xmlOutput">
    <jobDetails>
      <orderId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Order/OrderId"/>
      </orderId>
      <xsl:variable name="jobId" select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/OrderLineId" />
      <orderLine>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($jobId,'d')"/>
      </orderLine>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine">
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/>
        </name>
        <copies>
          <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
        </copies>
        <url>
          <xsl:value-of select="AssetUrl"/>
        </url>
        <nestQueueName>smile_test</nestQueueName>
        <customer_info>
          <first_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/Customer/FirstName"/>
          </first_name>
          <last_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/Customer/LastName"/>
          </last_name>
          <street1>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Address1"/>
          </street1>
          <street2>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Address2"/>
          </street2>
          <city>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Town"/>
          </city>
          <state>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/State"/>
          </state>
          <country>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Country"/>
          </country>
          <phone>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Phone"/>
          </phone>
          <email>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Order/ShippingAddress/Email"/>
          </email>

        </customer_info>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </jobDetails>
  </xsl:template>

<!--Convert XML to JSON-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="xmlOutputVar">
      <xsl:call-template name="xmlOutput"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($xmlOutputVar)/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Object or Element Property-->
  <xsl:template match="*">
        "    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
" :    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Array Element -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Object Properties -->
  <xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
"</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "        <xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>
" :[        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>
] }</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Attribute Property -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">"    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
" : "    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
",
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it's producing a different output to if I run the two transformations as separate XSL files.

If I run them separately, I end up with:

```
{

    "jobDetails" :{

    "orderId" :"1234",
    "orderLine" :"",
    "name" :"ProductName",
    "copies" :"1",
    "url" :"urlGoesHere",
    "nestQueueName" :"smile_test",
    "customer_info" :{

    "first_name" :"TestFirst",
    "last_name" :"TestLast",
    "street1" :"BALO",
    "street2" :"",
    "city" :"BAT",
    "state" :"Aberdeenshire",
    "country" :"United Kingdom",
    "phone" :"",
    "email" :"test@email.com"
            }
            }}
```

However, if I run them in the same XSL file, I end up with:

```
        "    jobDetails
" :    {

        "    orderId
" :    "        1234
",
        "    orderLine
" :    "        
",
        "    name
" :    "        ProductName
",
        "    copies
" :    "        1
",
        "    url
" :    "        urlGoesHere
",
        "    nestQueueName
" :    "        smile_test
",
        "    customer_info
" :    {

        "    first_name
" :    "        TestFirst
",
        "    last_name
" :    "        TestLast
",
        "    street1
" :    "        BALO
",
        "    street2
" :    "        
",
        "    city
" :    "        BAT
",
        "    state
" :    "        Aberdeenshire
",
        "    country
" :    "        United Kingdom
",
        "    phone
" :    "        
",
        "    email
" :    "        test@email.com
"
    }
    }
```

I can't see what would be causing the different outputs, can someone help with this as well please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlOutputVar">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlOutputVar">
  <xsl:call-template name="xmlOutput"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then use the supported extension function like e.g. `exsl:node-set` and replace

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$xmlOutputVar"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($xmlOutputVar)/node()" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's caused the templates to run in sequence, but it's generating a different output to when I run them as two different files.
Thank you for fixing the first half of my problem, I've edited the question in the hopes that someone can help me fix the second half haha

Comment: @bmitchellhyv, I don't see why the part trying to generate JSON would not spew out all the whitespace you have hardcode in those templates like in the one commented with `<!-- Object or Element Property-->`. There you explicitly create whitespace, as in other templates.

Comment: I didn't even realise - those whitespaces were added when I used a visual studio plugin to format as XML and I was so focused on getting the pipeline to work that I didn't think to check the hardcoded characters.

Removing the whitespace has fixed the issue fully, thank you!